# Location filter tweepy module

Tags: location, coordinates, tweepy

Hi I am trying to get tweets from Brazil only. This is my code, but I want to know if there is a way to get the location more tight so that it doesnt include the neighboring countries (i.e. having other shape for the region instead of the square).

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('brasil.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
    return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
    return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())    
sapi.filter(locations=[-74.1,-34.3,-34.1,5.6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The answer can be found here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters.html